# jQuery Tools Alternative

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am a big fan of [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html). It allows us to use one main set of plugins - all made to work with each other - and therefore implement only jQuery + jQuery tools, and automatically we can select a very wide variety of effects and tools. I prefer this over having to look for different plugins everytime a common effect is needed.

However, there is one big issue. The latest release is from Sep 2010. And nothing indicates the tools are being actively maintained. So I figure I need an alternative. What can you recommend? I guess jQuery UI is more or less the same, but I really feel jQuery Tools  had a very good focus on the visual aspects, as well as HTML5 coding, which I have not seen as much in jQuery UI.

Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: The activity on Github indicates that development is still occurring. https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/network

Comment: @Talljoe all the activity there are from forks though - last official commit was more than 5 months ago.

Comment: The last official commit on master; the branches dev and 1.3.0 are busy: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While jQuery UI requires a little more work to fine tune the UI and polish it off visually, ultimately it is one of the better options available. I has terrific support, a very active development trac, and very customizable packages also. I've been using it for a long time now, on both personal and commercial work, and always been happy with the results.